# how can I add gesture on CallOutBubble

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, mkannotationview

In my iphone app I want to allow the user to tap on the callout bubble to take him to another view 
how can i add gesture to the bubble

i tried to put gesture on the MKAnnotationView when the user select the annotation

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showItem:)];
   tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   [view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
}
```

but this doesn't work for the bubble 
any help ?

Comment: The recommended behavior is to add a right accessory view, and I would advise you to do so at first. It is easier for the user to find he(she) can tap. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You've set a gesture recognizer on the annotation view (the pin), not the callout bubble which is a separate view. On top of that, I'm not sure that recognizer will work due to conflicts with the map's recognizers.
2. As @CyrilGodefroy comments, what you're doing is both harder than and less recognizable to users than is the standard way of putting controls in the callout bubble. The framework provides callout accessory views for this purpose:

   ```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
       // Add a detail disclosure button to the callout.
       UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
       [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myShowDetailsMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
   }
   ```

Comment: What's frustrating is when you add a control to the callout, the callout suddently becomes selectable (meaning I can tap on it, and it highlights) but you can't detect this selection outside of the control (but on the callout bubble). This is confusing to the user because they have to precisely click on the button to get an action but tapping on the callout bubble highlights, which is typically a signal for "selection and action". AppleMaps has the same behavior for clicking on the callout or on a controller, but I haven't been able to figure out how to replicate

Answer (score 0):

The desired behavior is to be able to tap anywhere in the callout bubble and have it perform the action of the button in rightCalloutAccessory.

It's desired because adding a UIControl to either calloutAccessory makes the entire callout bubble selectable (meaning it highlights when you tap it, falsely indicating to the user that this should produce an action), but doesn't provide the implementer any way of detecting and responding to this tap, which results in a confusing user experience.

Here's how I solved the issue.

When creating the MKAnnotationView, add a tapGesture to the MKAnnotationView

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKAnnotationView *aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotation.reuseID];
aView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:annotation.callOutImageName]];
    aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = image;

    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [obsDetailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapOnCallout = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(calloutTapped:)];
    [aView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapOnCallout];

}
```

Then, in your callback method for the gesture, check if the annotationView is selected, and if so, perform your desired action

```
- (void)calloutTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)sender.view;

    if (annotationView.selected) {
        //Perform desired action on selection
    }  
}
```

Now this isn't a "perfect" solution because if you tap on the annotation once, to display the callout, and then tap the annotaiton (not the callout) while the callout is displayed, the action is peformed. However, I think this is a more intuitive experience than having your callout highlight without any action happening, so given the choices, I prefer this.

Obviously the ideal solution would be for Apple to expose the default callout view and allow you to directly add a gestureRecognizer to it. Or even better, for it to provide a delegate method that tells you the callout was tapped.

Until that happens, this is the best solution I could come up with. Hope it helps someone!